# Batch file: IF NOT X%5==X

Tags: file, batch-file

In a batch file, what is this "IF NOT X%5==X"?  I know it's an if statement and %5 is the fifth argument.  What does X%5 mean?  And what does it mean to compare it to X?

Answer (score 4):

I haven't written a DOS batch file for ages :) but I think it resembles a technique used in Unix shell scripts as well: expression `X%5==X` evaluates to true if the fifth parameter doesn't exist, i.e. there is less then 5 parameters passed to the script. The shell (command.com or whatever) replaces `%5` with the parameter, which is an empty string if less then 5 parameters were supplied, which reduces the expression to `X==X` (so: true).

Answer (score 3):

this will check if the 5th argument is defined. E.g. if 5th argument is not defined then you'll have `IF NOT X==X`  => fifth argument is not passed.if it has some value e.g. `fifth_arg_value` you'll have `IF NOT Xfifth_arg_value==X` strings will be not equal and you'll know that a value is passed to the 5th argument.