# Understanding if <string>.==.<string>

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

I believe I understand how to use if statements. However, I have a batch file that uses the following if statement

```
if %1.==. (
            Set iniFile=
            ) else (
            Set iniFile=--ini=%1
            )
```

This was written by someone else and I am trying to understand it and make a few changes. I do not understand the (.) before and after the == comparison. What is the significance of the (.)?

Comment: That's used to check whether `%1` is defined. _(a parameter wasn't passed)_.

Comment: Consider it is a shorthand for: `if "%1." == "."` (aka: `if s1 == s2`). That is, it is equal if and only if `%1` expands to an empty string (in which case `"." == "."` is true). The '.' thus fills in as a syntax place-holder; the "." symbols is not an operator, but it has the properties it is considered as text (so that it doesn't need to be quoted like `"."`) and that it is not allowed in a [%n] variable, so `%1.` is parsed as `%1` and `.`.

Comment: Thanks...for clarification is this different than using  IF "%~1" == "" or another way of accomplishing the same thing?

Comment: This is an old and strange notation that shouldn't be used; its purpose is to detect an empty parameter. You should use this instead: `if "%~1" == "" (`.

Comment: any characters can be used like that for checking empty variables, but x seems to be more common [IF NOT X%5==X](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19798748/995714), [Batch files for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28779561/995714)

Comment: Thanks for the help, this helped me to understand and modify the batch file. User2864740 was most helpful